# Error Get request PHP

Tags: php, api

I must send GET request to remote server to get some JSON data with PHP.
But i get Alert window with error:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

    http://duty.megafon.tj/VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js?v=7.4.3 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

    l.php:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: vaadin is not defined
```

This is my PHP code:

```
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/&clientId=m&clientSecret=m');
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
@curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'(http://example.com/&clientId=m&clientSecret=m)');
$date = curl_exec($ch);
echo($date);
@curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: `http://example.com/&clientId=m&clientSecret=m` invalid url; First `&` should be `?`. that's why its 404

Comment: Google for what a USERAGENT is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your PHP code to:

```
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/?clientId=m&clientSecret=m');
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
@curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'(http://example.com/&clientId=m&clientSecret=m)');
$date = curl_exec($ch);
echo($date);
@curl_close($ch);
```